# Issue with "spool"-commands in PL SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, export-to-csv, procedure, spool

I was trying to create a procedure within one of the Oracle DBs. Procedure is intended for my colleagues, so that everybody could export the result of the query in a csv-file.

I was using "spool" commands. When running the code between BEGIN and END separately in Oracle SQL Developer (running as script, F5) - it worked, and created the file locally.

Then I tried to put it in the procedure, and that is where issue began. Some compilation errors come out. Most of them have code "PLS-00103". I tried searching for it, but not successful so far. I even tried EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, putting some script blocks inside it - not working so far.

I will appreciate any hints/help on approaching my situation.

P.s. one of my first attempts is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE export_to_csv (SOURCE IN VARCHAR2, EXPORT_PATH IN VARCHAR2) is
BEGIN
   spool on;
   set feedback off;
   set heading off; ​ ​ ​
   set sqlformat csv;
   spool EXPORT_PATH;

   select * from SOURCE; 
   spool off;
END export_to_csv;
```

Comment: PL/SQL runs in the database and has no output stream. That’s why it has no `spool` command in its [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/toc.htm) and why `select` requires an `into` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that won't work. `SPOOL`, as well as all `SET` commands you use, are **SQL*Plus**.

Stored procedure is PL/SQL, so - if you want to do it from there, you'll have to use `UTL_FILE` package. The result will be on the database server, not your local PC.

---

Alternatively:

- put those `SPOOL, SET, SELECT`, ... commands into a .SQL file on the database server
- create a database job using `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package which is capable of running operating system files. On MS Windows, you'd call `CMD` which establishes connection to the database using `SQLPLUS` executable and calls your .SQL script (using `@`)
- just like in the previous option, the result will be on the database server, not on a local PC

---

See which option you prefer.

**Maybe** it would be simpler to create that .SQL file and give it to all your colleagues who'd then run it on their PCs and get the result locally.